# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException error when I access the OSGI bundle with JPA support

Tags: java, osgi, openjpa, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am using OpenJPA as JPA provider. I have created the small OSGI bundle project with the JPA2.0 support. This bundle provides the persistnce functionality to its clients.

I created another client bundle to consume the above persistence service. When I start the client bundle service using **Felix framework** I am getting bellow error,

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException**

**Complete stacktrace**

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle StudentServiceConsumer [120].
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2027)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:729)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Console.run(Console.java:62)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.console(Shell.java:203)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
        at com.student.serviceprovider.serviceimpl.StudentDAOService.persist(StudentDAOService.java:19)
        at com.student.serviceconsumer.activator.Activator.start(Activator.java:30)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException not found by org.apache.openjpa [109]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1460)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 36 more
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException**
```

Currently bellow bundles are in active state

```
 ID|State      |Level|Name
   0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.0.3)
   1|Active     |    1|file:/C:/Felix/felix-framework-4.0.3/bundle/junit.jar (0.0.0)
   2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
   3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
   4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
   5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
   7|Active     |    1|WS_J2EE_persistence (7.0.0)
 105|Active     |    1|file:/C:/Felix/felix-framework-4.0.3/bundle/commons-logging-4.0.6.jar (0.0.0)
 106|Active     |    1|Apache Commons Lang (2.6.0.v201205030909)
 107|Active     |    1|Apache Commons Logging Plug-in (1.0.4.v201101211617)
 109|Active     |    1|OpenJPA Plug-in (1.2.1.201001181728)
 114|Active     |    1|file:/C:/Felix/felix-framework-4.0.3/bundle/rt.jar (0.0.0)
 119|Active     |    1|StudentServiceProvider (1.0.0.201303061113)
```

**MENIFEST.MF(Service Bundle)**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: StudentServiceProvider
Bundle-SymbolicName: StudentServiceProvider
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.student.serviceprovider.activator.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
Export-Package: com.student.serviceprovider.model,
 com.student.serviceprovider.service,
 com.student.serviceprovider.serviceimpl
Bundle-ClassPath: ../lib/com.ibm.ws.jpa.jar,
 ../lib/commons-collections-20040616.jar,
 ../lib/j2ee.jar,
 ../lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar,
 .
Require-Bundle: org.apache.openjpa;bundle-version="1.2.1",
 org.apache.commons.logging;bundle-version="1.0.4"
```

**MENIFEST.MF(Client Bundle)**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: StudentServiceConsumer
Bundle-SymbolicName: StudentServiceConsumer
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.student.serviceconsumer.activator.Activator
Import-Package: com.student.serviceprovider.model,
 com.student.serviceprovider.service,
 com.student.serviceprovider.serviceimpl,
 org.osgi.framework
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: com.student.serviceconsumer.activator
```

I am very new to OSGI bundle development. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you using a JPA service provider like the one provided by Apache Aries? You can still use OpenJPA, but using it on its own in an OSGi environment usually doesn't work so well.

Answer (score 3):

Your client bundle need to import package `javax.naming`. Add this to the list of imported packages indicated by `Import-Package`.

By the way you might have additional dependencies that will be found to be missing after you resolve the problem with `javax.naming`. You really shouldn't write your MANIFEST.MF by hand because it is error-prone and contains duplicate information. You should use a tool like [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) or [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/).

**Update:** In fact, OpenJPA itself fails to import the package `javax.naming`, as shown by the following part of the stack trace: "javax.naming.NamingException not found by org.apache.openjpa [109]".

Therefore, OpenJPA is broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Neil, but still I am getting the same error. I am using IBM Rational Development tools for OSGI aplication. So, no need to write the MANIFEST.MF by hand. It will generate. I got it from eclipse market place. Currently I am using openJpa bundle version 1.2.1. May this doesst support for JPA2.0. I cound find the OpenJPA bundle foe the OpenJPA version 2. Please advice me where I went wrong.

Comment: Oh I see on closer inspection of the error message, it's actually OpenJPA itself that fails to import the `javax.naming` package. In that case, OpenJPA is broken. Please report a bug.

Comment: As for where you went wrong... first, you used JPA... then you used IBM Rational tools ;-)

Comment: Thanks Neil. I uesed IBM Rational Development tools to create this OSGI bundle. It supports to create the bundle with JPA 2.0 support. As you mentioned above the issue with the OpenJPA. I will check it. By the way I want to ask anotehr question from you. I got this OpenJPA bundle from eclipse plugin. I think, it does not support with JPA2.0. (I add the OpenJPA plugin to eclipse and got the bundle from eclipse plugin folder.) Can you please let me know where can I het the OpenJpa bundle which supports with JPA2.0. <br> Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the tool assumes bootdelegation is on?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add javax.api as a dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using -Dosgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
this helped with my problem

Comment: Anyone using boot delegation should read https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Boot_Delegation.

Answer (score 0):

My cause its resolved in eclipse after check the checkbox 'Use default compliance settings

[image]